# Internet Explorer dev tools `computed` css for DIV shows display: `block` despite it showing that it's using display: `table-cell`

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

This is in IE 11. This image should clarify:

[image]

(Note that it's showing `DIV` not `div` - *shouldn't* be a problem, but some oddity)

I have a css selector `.div-table-row div { display: table-cell; }` in my CSS file. And I have some HTML elements:

```
<div class="div-table-row">
    <div id="info-general">...</div>
    <div id="info-address">...</div>
</div>
```

For some reason, these two nested div's are showing the computed css you see in the image, breaking the layout.

It seems like a contradiction. It says it's using `display: block` yet that it's acquiring it from a selector that gives `table-cell`. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Please use a proper browser like Chrome or Firefox for developing on ;-) Would be interesting to see what kind of output you see in either of those!

Comment: .......................k